# express-graphql resolver args is empty in resolver but info variableValues populated with name and value

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

Using `apollo-server-express` and `graphql-tools`, I am attempting to create a minimally viable schema from a JSON object:

```js
const books = [
  {
    "title": "Harry Potter",
    "author": 'J.K. Rowling',
    "slug": "harry_potter",
  },
  {
    "title": 'Jurassic Park',
    "author": 'Michael Crichton',
    "slug": "jurassic_park",
  },
];

// The GraphQL schema in string form
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
    book(title: String!): Book
  }
  type Book { title: String!, author: String!, slug: String! }
`;

// The resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => books,
    book: (_, { title }) => books.filter(book => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(book.title == title) {
          console.log('hack log resolve book _: ', JSON.stringify(book))
          resolve(JSON.stringify(book));
        }
      })
    }),
   },
   Book: {
     title: (root, args, context, info) => {
       //args is empty, need to match arg w book.title
       /*
       context:  {
        _extensionStack:
         GraphQLExtensionStack {
           extensions: [ [FormatErrorExtension], [CacheControlExtension] ]
         }
       }
       , root,
       */
       console.log('resolve Book args: ', args, 'info', info);//JSON.stringify(root.book))
       return books.filter(book => {
         if(book.title == root.title) {
           return book;
         }
       });//JSON.stringify({"title": root.title});
     }
   }
};
//    book: (_, { title }) => books.filter(book => book.title == title),


// Put together a schema
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
```

This is [my repository](https://github.com/Kielan/blog.kielanlemons.com-api).

When logging and stepping through `node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js`, the first param of execute `argsOrSchema.variableValues` contains the query argument key and value, however the 5th argument `variableValues` is undefined.

According to some threads such as [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1419) I can pull the `variableValues` from the `info` argument of my resolver, however I would still like to know why the `args` object is empty?

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/Kielan/7dcb3d98e31957351b1443951698d5ca)  of the info log given by GraphQL in the resolver function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `args` parameter is populated by the arguments passed to the field being resolved -- any arguments passed to *other* fields will not be included in the `args` parameter.

Your schema includes a single argument (`title`) on the `book` field of your `Query` type. That means the resolver for that field will receive the `title` argument as part of its `args` parameter, but only if that argument is actually included in your query:

```
// Request
query {
  book(title: "Something") {
    title
  }
}

// Resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    book: (root, args) => {
      console.log(args) // {title: 'Something'}
    }
  },
}
```

As opposed to:

```
// Request
query {
  book {
    title
  }
}

// Resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    book: (root, args) => {
      console.log(args) // {}
    }
  },
}
```

If you pass in a value for the `title` argument, the only way to get that value in resolvers for other fields is to parse the `info` parameter. You would not look at the `variableValues` property, though because the value passed to an argument could be a literal value or a variable. You'd need to traverse the `fieldNodes` array and locate the appropriate argument value instead.

However, there's typically no need to go through all that.

If the `book` field is supposed to just a return a book object, your logic for selecting the right book from the `books` array should be included in that field's resolver:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    book: (root, args) => {
      return books.find(book => book.title === args.title)
    }
  },
}
```

There is no reason to include a resolver for the `title` field on the `Book` type, unless you need that field to resolve to something other than what it will resolve to by default (the `title` property on the object returned by the parent field's resolver). This would be sufficient to query all books and an individual book by title:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    book: (root, args) => {
      return books.find(book => book.title === args.title)
    },
    books: () => books,
  },
}
```

Check out the [official tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers) from Apollo for more examples and a complete explanation of how resolvers work.